# How to make maps InfoWindowAdapter to set marker with model

Tags: android, google-maps

```
 googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {

                @Override
                public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

                        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                        View infoView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_sightings, null);
                        //showSightingInfoWindow(infoView, (Sighting) marker.getData());

                        return infoView;
                    }
            });
```

I am tring this but it does not give an option to add data model object in this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I display more than just the Title and Snippet in a Google Maps Custom Info Window?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30068639/how-can-i-display-more-than-just-the-title-and-snippet-in-a-google-maps-custom-i)

Comment: i have done it through snippet but i got new problem now iam not able to view image on click of marker in infolayout iam loading the image with Imageloader