# Show name of user above marker

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, firebase, infowindow

I have created an android apps that can show the other user location that saved in Firebase and then show marker of user in google maps. I have sucessfully show picture of user, and a title of "Name" for the user name, [like this picture of my screenshot of my apps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGPO4.png)
but now I have difficulty with show the name of user match with their picture and their location.

How to show the name of user like I show profile picture of user above the marker of their locations ? I want to show the username based stored data in Firebase

This is my code in CustomInfoWindowAdapter.java

```
public class CustomInfoWindowAdapter implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {

private View mymarkerview;
private Context context;

private Application app;
private Marker marker;
private Firebase ref;
private AuthData authData;
private String orig_display_name;
private TextView mDisplayName;

public CustomInfoWindowAdapter(Context context_given) {
    context = context_given;
    app = (Application) context;
}

public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {

    // PIN Marker.
    if (marker.getAlpha() == (float) .99) { return null; }

    // User Location Marker:
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    mymarkerview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_info_window, null);
    this.marker = marker;
    render();
    return mymarkerview;
}

public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
    return null;
}

private void render() {

    if (!marker.getTitle().equals("")) {
        ImageView image_disp = (ImageView) mymarkerview.findViewById(R.id.indiv_pro_pic);
        image_disp.setImageBitmap(Application.decodeBase64(marker.getTitle()));

        TextView mDisplayName = (TextView) mymarkerview.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        orig_display_name = ("Username");
        mDisplayName.setText(orig_display_name);
        }
    }

}
```

This is for custom_info_window.xml layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/indiv_pro_pic"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/unknownuser" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/txtName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:text="Nama User"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you post your `custom_info_window` layout?

Comment: Using the technique in this answer would solve it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30069852/4409409